# Passing arguments by reference to constructors of self-defined objects

Tags: c++

I have read the sometimes it is better to pass arguments by reference so that if the argument type is large in space, we will not copy it (as happens when we pass by reference).

But I dont quite see how it prevents all of the copies. For example consider the BinaryNode class:

```
template <class T>
class BinaryNode
{
    public:
    //|-------------------- Constructors --------------------
        BinaryNode(const T& _key):key(_key), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL){}
    protected:
        T key;
        BinaryNode* left;
        BinaryNode* right;
        BinaryNode* parent;
};
```

When we declare of new BinaryNode, an element T key is created, and even though we pass by reference the argument, still the copy operator = is being activated and still we got ourselves a copy.

So, is there a way to prevent it? or maybe it is not really a bad thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre], then [edit] your question to give sufficient details.

Comment: May I politely remind you that you're required to post a [mcve] here, to help in diagnosing such problems! Otherwise we'll consider your question off-topic, and it become closed and deleted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My question is theoretical, what example could I possibly give?

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper so [edit] your question, and elaborate about your theory. But c++ is a well defined language, regarding it's guaranteed behaviors. Maybe try grounding at that, and trying to compile your code examples successfully, or not of course.

Comment: Theoretical questions are off-topic. According to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." See also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used

```
BinaryNode(T _key):key(_key), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL){}
```

, then there would be potentially two copies if the argument is a lvalue. One copy construction from the constructor argument to the parameter and one from the parameter to the member.

You would usually avoid copies by preferring *move* operations instead. For this you can overload for lvalues which need to be copied and rvalues which can be moved:

```
 BinaryNode(const T& _key):key(_key), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL){}
 BinaryNode(T&& _key):key(std::move(_key)), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL){}
```

which makes a single copy construction if necessary (if the argument to the constructor is a lvalue) and otherwise makes a single move construction via the second overload.

Or with a minimal penalty that usually shouldn't matter you can use a single overload:

```
BinaryNode(T _key):key(std::move(_key)), left(NULL), right(NULL), parent(NULL){}
```

which will potentially do one move construction or copy construction to the parameter, depending on whether the constructor argument is a lvalue or rvalue, and whether or not the object is directly constructed in the argument, and one additional move construction to construct the member.

---

Note that in none of this the assignment operator `operator=` is used. Only constructors are called.

---

If the argument to the constructor is a lvalue, then a copy construction cannot be avoided, otherwise a move construction cannot be avoided.